# How can I detect simultaneous button presses

Tags: c, wiringpi

I want to make button 1 and 2 silent when both are pressed at the same time. It works... but only sometimes. Sometimes it will only print "sim pressed" and other times it will say "Button-1 Clicked" and "Sim pressed"

I want to make it so when btn 1 and btn 2 are pressed at the same time they don't print "button-1 clicked" or "button-2 clicked" but they print "sim pressed"

How could I make this happen?

I've tried researching simultaneous button presses but I myself couldn't find anything for wiringPi

Includes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define sd 200
#define pin1 8
#define pin2 7

int a, b, c = 1;
```

Button 1 button Press

```
void *btn1() {
    while(1) {
        if(!digitalRead(pin1) && digitalRead(pin2) && a) {
            a = 0;
            printf("Button-1 pressed\n");
            delay(sd);
        }
        if(digitalRead(pin1) && !a) {
            a = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Button 2 button press

```
void *btn2() {
    while(1) {
        if(!digitalRead(pin2) && digitalRead(pin1) && b) {
            b = 0;
            printf("Button-2 pressed\n");
            delay(sd);
        }
        if(digitalRead(pin2) && !b) {
            b = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Simultaneous button press

```
void *simbtn() {
    while(1) {
        if(!digitalRead(pin1) && !digitalRead(pin2) && c) {
            c = 0;
            printf("Sim pressed\n");
            delay(sd);
        }
        if(digitalRead(pin1) && digitalRead(pin2) && !c) {
            c = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the thread

```
int main(void) {
    wiringPiSetupGpio();

    pthread_t tid[2];
    pthread_create(&tid[0], NULL, btn1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[1], NULL, btn2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[2], NULL, simbtn, NULL);

    while(1) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Expected result once btn 1 and 2 pressed simultaneously:

```
Sim pressed
```

Actual result when both are pressed (6 times to give a good example):

```
Button-1 pressed
Sim pressed
Button-1 pressed
sim pressed
button-2 pressed
sim pressed
Button-1 pressed
Sim pressed
Button-2 pressed
sim pressed
button-2 pressed
sim pressed
```

Comment: Why the threads?

Comment: so multiple can be done at once .-.

Comment: I don't know wiringpi but does judging from your code, it doesn't define the concept of simultaneous button presses meaning you probably need to start some sort of timer as soon as one button pressed is recognized and wait a previously defined amount of time before giving up on the second button press and declaring it non-simultaneous.

Comment: Do you know any that do work with simultaneous button presses without the use of timers etc?

Comment: Multiple threads don't run at the same time.  It is inefficient to put threads in the same process on different cores, since it breaks caching.

Comment: Nope? I've already tried without threads, doesn't work the same way lawl